# how to search data from array if matches any of the character of any value in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am using following code to get the index value of the particular but now it will show a but i want that it may show all the index values having character a
Like we do searching

```
    var con = document.getElementById('data');

    var char = 'a';
    var str = '';
    var ad = ['abc', 'a', 'call', 'all', 'ded', 'ee', 'aee'];
    var count = ad.filter(function (v) {
     return v == char;
    }).length;

   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
   str += char;

   alert(str);

   con.innerHTML = str;
```

here is the jsfiddel link

http://jsfiddle.net/Pescf/7/

Comment: Try .indexOf() function

Comment: @Dineshkani can you please help me out and edit in code please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/Pescf/11/

Comment: @Dineshkani it is working but instead of showing a only it should show all the value of that index compelt lik ali call etc

Comment: See below Answer for your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below, it will help you...

**Updated Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/Pescf/24/

```
var con = document.getElementById('data');
var char = 'a';
var str = '';
var ad = ['ali', 'bbc', 'call', 'a', 'd', 'eaa', 'ab'];
var len = ad.length;
for (var j=0; j<len; j++) {
    var str = ad[j];
    var n=str.indexOf(char);
        if (n==0) 
            con.innerHTML += str + "<br>";
    }
```

its output is like below...

```
ali
a
ab
```

Comment: i want like search if var is only al then it show ali only not call a or eaa and if i enter ca then it should show call

Comment: check the code while putting a in var it may show only ali ab and a but it showing all the values of a

Answer (score 0):

Given the new requirement that the character be at the beginning of the string:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/Pescf/26/

---

If you need to keep track of the current array element, the best way would probably to just iterate over the entire array and not just the number of elements in the array that have the character.

Inside the for loop, just check for whether the current item has the character in it: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/Pescf/13/

---

I think I understand... Try replacing `return v == char;` with `return v.indexOf(char) !== -1`. Currently count only equals 1, so it won't do what you want. Changing this will cause count to equal 5, getting you the result you desire (I think).

The reason that `return v == char` doesn't work is because you are testing whether or not the full string equals a single character, which only exists one time.

Instead, `indexOf` will check to see if a string contains a character.

Comment: yes but it show value of that index that has a it just shows now a for all

Comment: Your code says to add str (blank string) to the character you define plus a line break... If you want it to display the actual string that it matched, there will have to be other changes. I gave you a response to what could have been confusing. The other change shouldn't be difficult to find out.

Comment: Currently you are just appending the character you hard coded in. You will need to append the array element at the current index in  your for loop.

Comment: i am new to java script can you please edit this in jfiddle please

Comment: i want like we normally do in search engine if i give var al then it may show only al and if var ic ca then it show in this call only

Comment: @ShahzadAli I can't understand what you just said.

Comment: i am saying that as normally in search enginens if var is a then it may show all the values start with a and if var is ca then it show values haveing ca at start as we normally do in search

Comment: this is not the new requirement but it is the way of searching

Comment: @ShahzadAli you could be using this for any multitude of reasons. You can't assume we know what you want. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var con = document.getElementById('data');
var char = 'a';
var str = '';
var ad = ['ali', 'bbc', 'call', 'a', 'd', 'eaa', 'ab'];
for (var i = 0; i < ad.length; i++)
  if (ad[i].indexOf(char) != -1)
      str += ad[i] + "<br/>";
con.innerHTML = str+'\n
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/Pescf/12/)

**Updated**

See the below demo give your search string it shows like a search engine optimize your code for your convenience.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/Pescf/29/)

Comment: can we make like this a then it may show only ali a becuase it starts with as we normally we do in search i want that one enters bb then it show only bbc not ab

Comment: have tried and searched but i am not getting this i also searched on forums

Comment: @ShahzadAli With in indexOf('Search String') you put your search query then it shows what you want exactly See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/Pescf/20/

Comment: it is not working correct please test it when give var c the it shows bbc it may show call